# Function not working without contentType: 'application/json'

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-ajax

My problem is that success function in the ajax works but error not working but if add to ***contentType: 'application/json'*** work always error function.

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { pollCodeInput: pollCodeInput, pollNameInput: pollNameInput, promotionPoints: promotionPoints },
                    url: "http://Work.local/mvc/KeyFacts/CreatePoll2",                       
                    //contentType: 'application/json',
                    success: function () {
                        openNav();
                        $('#modal').removeClass('modal-open');                         
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("error!");
                    }                             
               });

            });
```

When i am debugging my Controller works correctly.This is my Controller;

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreatePoll2(string pollCodeInput, string pollNameInput, int promotionPoints = 0)
    {
        MethodResult result = BusinessComponentRegistry.SingleInstance.PollManager.Create(pollCodeInput,
            pollNameInput, 0);
        if (result.HasErrors)
        {
            ViewBag.ErrorCreatePoll = result.Messages.ToString();
            return Json(new { success = false, responseText = "The attached file is not supported." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.SuccessCreatePoll = result.Messages.ToString();             
            return Json(new { success = true, error = false, responseText = "Success!!" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
          }
    }
```

Comment: Check the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) on how to get some useful informations from the error handler instead of only alerting "error!"

Comment: Why would you expect the `error:` handler to kick in if you return a successful result?   Just because that successful result contains a boolean, it's still a success.

Comment: You either need to handle the `success=false` in the `success:` handler or not return a valid (200) result, eg `if (result.HasErrors) throw new InvalidOperation(`Not supported')`

Comment: have you tried this one "  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8","

Comment: Actually, i do not understand very well but if(result.HasErrors) function work for eg : user enter the null or existing pollCode and it  is work correctly even if shown success function does not save existing pollCode or null pollCode

Comment: Yes, i tried to " contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" nothing change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your ActionResult is *returning* OK (http 200) because both branches return valid `Json`

```
return Json(new ...
```

so the `ajax` call always hits the `success:` callback.

Inside your action, you handle the case where the PollManager didn't create correctly and return as Success *result* to the ajax.

Within that result is a flag saying that "success" was false, but this is not the *same* success that would be used for the `success:` callback - there's no configuration-by-convention here.   You could just as easily call that value something else, eg:

```
return Json(new { workedlikeacharm = false ...
```

So the best (IMO) option here is to keep the action as it is, returning a valid result to the ajax with a flag saying what to do, and handle it within the `success:` callback, eg:

```
success:function(result) {
    if (result.success == true) {
        openNav();
        $('#modal').removeClass('modal-open');
    } else {
        alert(result.responseText);
    }
```

However, if you want to keep the ajax success/fail and change the Action, then you change what you are returning:

```
if (result.HasErrors)
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(500, "file is not supported");
```

as this now returns a 500 not a 200 (200 is implied with a valid `return new Json(..`) then the javascript code will hit the `error:` callback.

Alternatively, you can just throw an exception (which will generate a 500 status code result), eg:

```
if (result.HasErrors)
    throw new InvalidOperationException("file is not supported");
```

in both cases, if you want to see the message, you'll have to update your `error:` handler to read the http status message.

Comment: Thank you , I realized  problem now and came to edit my post but this answer really clear and understandable

Answer (score 0):

first of all please make object of your all parameter

```
   var obj = {};
        obj.first_name = $("#FirstName").val();
        obj.last_name = $("#LastName").val();
        obj.email_id = $("#Email").val().toLowerCase();
        obj.gender = $("#Gender").val();
        obj.birth_date = $("#BirthDate").val();
        obj.address = $("#Address").val();
        obj.cell_phone = $("#Phone").val();
        obj.user_name = $("#UserName").val();
        obj.password = $("#Password").val();
        obj.security_question = $("#SecurityQuestion").val();
        obj.security_answer = $("#SecurityAnswer").val();   
        obj.role_id = $("#EmployeeType").val();
        obj.access_level = $("#AccessLevel").val();
        obj.business_id = businessId;
        obj.isActive = "true";
        obj.teamlead_id = $("#TeamleadName").val();
        obj.projectlead_id = $("#ProjectleadName").val();
        obj.manager_id = $("#ManagerName").val();
```

Now Convert Them with this json method

```
   dataValue = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

And Use It Like This

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: strUrl,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: dataValue,
        async: false,
        success: onSuccess,
        error: function (err) {
            callLoader(false);
            swal({
                title: "Something Wents Wrong", text: "", type: "error",
                showCancelButton: false, closeOnConfirm: true, confirmButtonText: "OK",
            }, function (isConfirm) {
                window.location = "signin";
            });
            // console.log(err);
        }
    });
}
```